# How can I pass data with + character in an AJAX call?

Tags: php, ajax, character

I am trying to send data using an AJAX call to the server (target.php) as below:

```
var data = "productid="+productid+"&title="+title;
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url + "target.php",
  data: data,
  dataType: "json"})
```

However title contains special characters as below:

```
title = "Car+Bikes"
```

Apparently the + character is replaced with a blank character:

```
title = "Car Bikes"
```

Is there an easy way to solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Why dont you send the data as array instead of a string? Its way cleaner and you wont run into those problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send data in json

```
data: { productid: productid, title: title }
```

Comment: Adding some explanation about how this avoids the default behavior for strings which is to url encode them would be helpful.

Comment: If you want to use `$_GET['title']` so write stringify parameters in url `url: url + "target.php?productid="+productid+"&title="+title;` else to use `$_POST['title']` forward in data.